# Does Windows Azure have the equivalent of AWS Identity Access Management?

Tags: azure, amazon-iam

So I have a mobile app that uses AWS's IAM infrastructure that effectively allows me to provide temporary access tokens to anonymous mobile devices, so that they can run queries against AWS services directly from the mobile device.

Does anyone know if Windows Azure has a drop in replacement for this sort of thing too? I've read about Windows Azure Access Control but all examples seem to focus on allowing authentication via the likes of Facebook, Twitter or Windows Live etc. In my case, I don't want the mobile user to have to "log-in" anywhere, I just want them to be able to access Azure services such as table storage, without having to go via my server.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of queries you would want your users to run? Or in other words what kind of queries your users are able to run today against AWS resources?

Comment: For example, "select from X where" from Table Storage. Or downloading a blob from Blob Storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have the ability to create [Signed Access Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx) for all three Windows Azure Storage services (BLOBs, Queues and Tables) as well as for Windows Azure Service Bus Brokered Messages (Queues, Topics & Subscriptions).  These SAS urls are temporary and you can create them ad-hoc with expiration times.  After that time expires the device would have to request a new one, likely from your server.  This reduce the load as they aren't coming back all the time, but you do still have to run something that will gen these SAS uris for the devices.  You can generate SAS manually against the REST API direct, or you can use one of the SDKs to generate them for you (which also hit the REST API).

Note that when you create a SAS you have the option of doing so as a Policy, or adhoc.  A policy allows you to revoke a SAS at a later time, but you can only have so many of these defined at a time (likely too big of a restriction for a mobile scenario if you are doing by device).  The adhoc approach allows you pretty much as many as you need (I think), but you don't have the ability to revoke it, it just has to expire.

Another option is to look at Windows Azure Mobile Services.  This service runs on servers managed by Microsoft and you can use it to get at just about anything you want.  You'd want to look at the "[Custom API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn280974.aspx)" feature.  Also, make sure you understand the [pricing model](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/) of mobile services (or really, that stands for any option you decide to go with).

Comment: Thanks! Shared Access Signatures looks like exactly what I've been looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's called managed identities in Azure