# Is there any instace profile available in Azure like in AWS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, amazon-iam

An instance profile is a container for an IAM role that you can use to pass role information to an EC2 instance when the instance starts.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html

Comment: Do you mean permission control for your resource? Azure supports RABC to control permission. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is)

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I mean like this in [AWS instance profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html)

Comment: @kanran Based on my knowledge, Azure supports IAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure also supports IAM.

Microsoft Azure identity and access management solutions help IT protect access to applications and
resources across the corporate data center and into the cloud. This enables additional levels of validation,
such as multifactor authentication and conditional access policies. Monitoring suspicious activity through
advanced security reporting, auditing and alerting helps mitigate potential security issues.

More detailed information please refer to this [link](https://www.insight.com/content/dam/insight-web/en_US/article-images/datasheets/Microsoft-Azure-IAM-DS.pdf).

Update:

You do have the ability to create Signed Access Signatures for all three Windows Azure Storage services (BLOBs, Queues and Tables) as well as for Windows Azure Service Bus Brokered Messages (Queues, Topics & Subscriptions). I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634925/does-windows-azure-have-the-equivalent-of-aws-identity-access-management) with you, maybe you could check.

Comment: Is there any other document available for Azure IAM to work with ? Is Azure IAM and Azure Active Directory (AAD) are same ?

Comment: No, they are different. Hi karan, I find a similar question with you, maybe you could check. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634925/does-windows-azure-have-the-equivalent-of-aws-identity-access-management

Answer (score 3):

A mechanism very similar to AWS instance profiles is [Managed Service Identity (MSI) for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-overview), which was [announced in September 2017](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/keep-credentials-out-of-code-introducing-azure-ad-managed-service-identity/), though at the time of this writing, it is still in preview. I didn't try it out yet, but it does work the same way as instance profiles on AWS do, by automatically authenticating the VM to a meta-data service and allowing you to query for additional credentials without having to hardcode it into your code or image.

Answer (score 0):

I found Azure is not support instance profile like aws.

If bind a role to instance on aws, aws system will generate a temporary api access token and write to metadata server.

Aws sdk will auto fetch access token from metadata server, so a service that uses aws sdk does not need to configure sdk's access token.

But Azure's IAM and SAS(shared access signature) and metadata server, is not support mechanism like above.